# Conda python3.6 No moduled named 'Quandl'

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, quandl

I tried to run my code which has import Quandl. The below error occur. I have already install quandl via pip, conda and whl files and all of these ways do not work.

```
runfile('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/New folder/stock reinforce/untitled6.py', wdir='C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/New folder/stock reinforce')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-adf3164815a5>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/New folder/stock reinforce/untitled6.py', wdir='C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/New folder/stock reinforce')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/New folder/stock reinforce/untitled6.py", line 15, in <module>
    import Quandl

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quandl'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import is case sensitive. Maybe you'll have better luck with:

```
import quandl
```

per https://www.quandl.com/tools/python

Comment: It works.Thank you so  much you save my time. But the another problem occur that is FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/XBTEUR_1day.pkl'.

Comment: That's a different problem - where is your `data/XBTEUR_1day.pkl` files?

Comment: def read_convert_data(symbol='XBTEUR'):
    if symbol == 'XBTEUR':
        prices = quandl.get("BCHARTS/KRAKENEUR")
        prices.to_pickle('data/XBTEUR_1day.pkl')

Comment: I think i will post another topic instead. Thank for your help

Comment: Topic link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408610/loading-the-data-from-quandl-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: I can fix my problem now by changing path 'data/XBTEUR_1day.pkl' to be my own directory path. And there are more changing path in this code until plt is the last one.